# MySQL Specific condition for each row in same query +PHP

Tags: php, mysql

> Please consider my tables

- store - table with information of all my stores
- zone - An alias table with zone_id and the name of the zone.
- store_zone - Table that contains the information when a store was changed to a different zone.
- cashdesk - table with local_id that contains information about the
  income for **each day** and each **store**

store_zone table:

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
| id | store_id | zone_id | modified_at |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |        1 |       2 | 2019-01-01  |
|  2 |        1 |       1 | 2019-01-04  |
|  3 |        2 |       4 | 2019-01-03  |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
```

- store_id is the foreign key for my local table id
- store table also contains a fk for zone_id
- zone_id  is the foreign key for my zone table id

> Now consider my problem:

- I need to select all stores
- get the sum(income) per row (stores)
- filter by zone
- consider only incomes that correspond to the local_zone table between
  dates. (if I select the whole month and a zone was changed the day
  15.. I only care about the 15 first days). I can use php to help build it.

something like:

```
$zone_modified_dates = //result of 
"SELECT modified_at 
FROM store_zone 
WHERE zone_id = 1 AND store_id = 1"
$zone_modified_dates = '2019-01-04'


SELECT sum(income) from cashdesk c
inner join store s ON s.id = c.store_id
inner join store_zone sz ON (sz.store_id = s.id AND sz.zone_id = z.id
WHERE zone_id = 1 
AND cashdesk created_at >= '2019-01-01' 
AND cashdesk created_at >= '2019-01-10'
AND //IF ZONE WAS CHANGED IN THIS CREATED_AT BETWEEN DATES ONLY CONSIDER THE DAYS THAT THE SPECIFIC ROW STORE WAS CONSIDERED ZONE 1
GROUP BY s.id
```

Thanks in advance.

@edited for better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Try to put some conditions yourself in `WHERE` part of your query. Provide some data set sample and expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Alex Added more information about the problem.

Comment: Yes it would really help if you could edit your question to provide sample data and expected output. As it is, it does not seem possible to provide an accurate answer.